# jsf - primefaces i can not get current ROW from database table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Netbeans with Primefaces. My problem is not to be able to use instant. Everything's going normal except p:dialog is empty when I click the row.

I cannot understand why the `getCurrent` method is working without Primefaces but not with Primefaces!

The codes are below.

Your help will be appreciated so much,

Thanks,

ArabaController.java code is as below:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "arabaController")
@SessionScoped
public class ArabaController implements Serializable {

   private primeController mediumCarsModel;  
   private primeController arabaList;
   private primeController getprimeAraba;
   private List<Araba> carsSmall; 
   private ArabaController y;
    private Araba current;
    private Araba selectedCar;
    private DataModel items = null;
    private String Marka;
    private String Model;
    private String Renk;
    private int Yil;
    private DataModel sel;
    public static  int deneme;
    @EJB
    private session.ArabaFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public Araba getSelected() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Araba();
            selectedItemIndex = -1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    private ArabaFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public PaginationHelper getPagination() {
        if (pagination == null) {
            pagination = new PaginationHelper(20) {

                @Override
                public int getItemsCount() {
                    return getFacade().count();
                }

                @Override
                public DataModel createPageDataModel() {
                    return new ListDataModel(getFacade().findRange(new int[]{getPageFirstItem(), getPageFirstItem() + getPageSize()}));
                }
            };
        }
        return pagination;
    }

    public String prepareList() {

        recreateModel();
        System.out.println("selim");
        return "List";
    }

    public String prepareView() {
        current = (Araba) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "View";
    }
    public Araba getCurrent(){
         selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();  
       current = (Araba) getItems().getRowData();

        System.out.println(selectedItemIndex) ;
        System.out.println(current);
        System.out.println("current");
     return current;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Seçilen Araba", ((Araba) event.getObject()).getMarka());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
   public void getSelectedMarka(SelectEvent event)
   {
   Marka=((Araba) event.getObject()).getMarka();
    return;
   }

    public String getSelectedModel(SelectEvent event)
   {
   Model=((Araba) event.getObject()).getModel();
   return Model;
   } 
    public String getSelectedRenk(SelectEvent event)
   {
   Renk=((Araba) event.getObject()).getRenk();
   return Renk;
   }

    public int getSelectedYil(SelectEvent event)
   {
   Yil=((Araba) event.getObject()).getYil();
   return Yil;
   }  

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public String prepareCreate() {
        current = new Araba();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
        return "Create";
    }

    public String create() {
        try {
            getFacade().create(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ArabaCreated"));
            return prepareCreate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String prepareEdit() {
        current = (Araba) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        return "Edit";
    }

    public String update() {
        try {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ArabaUpdated"));
            return "View";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String destroy() {
        current = (Araba) getItems().getRowData();
        selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();
        performDestroy();
        recreatePagination();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String destroyAndView() {
        performDestroy();
        recreateModel();
        updateCurrentItem();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            return "View";
        } else {
            // all items were removed - go back to list
            recreateModel();
            return "List";
        }
    }

    private void performDestroy() {
        try {
            getFacade().remove(current);
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ArabaDeleted"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    private void updateCurrentItem() {
        int count = getFacade().count();
        if (selectedItemIndex >= count) {
            // selected index cannot be bigger than number of items:
            selectedItemIndex = count - 1;
            // go to previous page if last page disappeared:
            if (pagination.getPageFirstItem() >= count) {
                pagination.previousPage();
            }
        }
        if (selectedItemIndex >= 0) {
            current = getFacade().findRange(new int[]{selectedItemIndex, selectedItemIndex + 1}).get(0);
        }
    }

    public DataModel getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
        }
        return items;
    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    private void recreatePagination() {
        pagination = null;
    }

    public String next() {
        getPagination().nextPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public String previous() {
        getPagination().previousPage();
        recreateModel();
        return "List";
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(), false);
    }

    public SelectItem[] getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {


        return JsfUtil.getSelectItems(ejbFacade.findAll(),true);


    }

    public Object getRowDataTable()
    {
        return sel.getRowData();
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Araba.class)
    public static class ArabaControllerConverter implements Converter {

        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            ArabaController controller = (ArabaController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "arabaController");
            return controller.ejbFacade.find(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Araba) {
                Araba o = (Araba) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getIdaraba());
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " +                        object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + ArabaController.class.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   public Araba getSelectedCar() { 


        return selectedCar;  
    }  
    public void setSelectedCar(Araba selectedCar) {  
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;  
    }  

     public primeController getMediumCarsModel() {  
       mediumCarsModel = new primeController(ejbFacade.findAll()); 
        return mediumCarsModel;
      }  
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
```

primecontroller.java is as below:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "primeController")
@SessionScoped
public  class primeController extends ListDataModel<Araba> implements SelectableDataModel<Araba> {

   private session.ArabaFacade x;
    private Araba current;
    private DataModel items = null;
    @EJB
    private session.ArabaFacade ejbFacade;
    private PaginationHelper pagination;
    private int selectedItemIndex;

    public primeController() {
    }
public primeController(List<Araba> data) {  
        super(data);  
    }  
  public List<Araba> sendAraba()
  {
      List<Araba> cars = x.findAll(); 
      return cars;
  }

    @Override  
    public Araba getRowData(String rowKey) {  
        //In a real app, a more efficient way like a query by rowKey should be implemented to deal with huge data  

        List<Araba> cars = x.findAll(); 
        System.out.print("olmalı idi");

        for(Araba car : cars) {  
            if(car.getModel().equals(rowKey))  
                return car;  
        }  

        return null;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public Object getRowKey(Araba car) {  
        controller.ArabaController.deneme=3;
        return car.getModel();  
    }  

}
```

araba.java (model) code is as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "araba")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findByIdaraba", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a WHERE a.idaraba = :idaraba"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findByMarka", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a WHERE a.marka = :marka"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findByRenk", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a WHERE a.renk = :renk"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findByYil", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a WHERE a.yil = :yil"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Araba.findByModel", query = "SELECT a FROM Araba a WHERE a.model = :model")})
public class Araba implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idaraba")
    private Integer idaraba;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "MARKA")
    private String marka;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "RENK")
    private String renk;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "YIL")
    private int yil;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "MODEL")
    private String model;

    public Araba() {
    }

    public Araba(Integer idaraba) {
        this.idaraba = idaraba;
    }

    public Araba(Integer idaraba, String marka, String renk, int yil, String model) {
        this.idaraba = idaraba;
        this.marka = marka;
        this.renk = renk;
        this.yil = yil;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Integer getIdaraba() {
        return idaraba;
    }

    public void setIdaraba(Integer idaraba) {
        this.idaraba = idaraba;
    }

    public String getMarka() {
        return marka;
    }

    public void setMarka(String marka) {
        this.marka = marka;
    }

    public String getRenk() {
        return renk;
    }

    public void setRenk(String renk) {
        this.renk = renk;
    }

    public int getYil() {
        return yil;
    }

    public void setYil(int yil) {
        this.yil = yil;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idaraba != null ? idaraba.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Araba)) {
            return false;
        }
        Araba other = (Araba) object;
        if ((this.idaraba == null && other.idaraba != null) || (this.idaraba != null && !this.idaraba.equals(other.idaraba))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "model.Araba[ idaraba=" + idaraba + " ]";
    }


}
```

session abstractfacade.java :

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<Araba> findAll() {
       // javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        //cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        //return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
        CriteriaBuilder cb= getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Araba> cq= cb.createQuery(Araba.class);
        Root<Araba> araba=cq.from(Araba.class);
        cq.select(araba);
        TypedQuery<Araba> q=getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        List<Araba> tumArabalar=q.getResultList();
         System.out.println("current");
        return tumArabalar;
    }

    public List<Araba> findRange(int[] range) {
       // javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
       // cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
       // javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        CriteriaBuilder cb= getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Araba> cq= cb.createQuery(Araba.class);
        Root<Araba> araba=cq.from(Araba.class);
        cq.select(araba);
        TypedQuery<Araba> q=getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

arabafacade.java:

```
@Stateless
public class ArabaFacade extends AbstractFacade<Araba> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplication1PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ArabaFacade() {
        super(Araba.class);
    }
}
```

List.XHTML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle}"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">

            <h:form id="form" styleClass="jsfcrud_list_form">
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>   
                <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bundle.ListArabaEmpty}" rendered="#{arabaController.items.rowCount == 0}"/>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{arabaController.items.rowCount > 0}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.pagination.pageFirstItem + 1}..#{arabaController.pagination.pageLastItem + 1}/#{arabaController.pagination.itemsCount}"/>&nbsp;
                    <h:commandLink action="#{arabaController.previous}" value="#{bundle.Previous} #{arabaController.pagination.pageSize}" rendered="#{arabaController.pagination.hasPreviousPage}"/>&nbsp;
                    <h:commandLink action="#{arabaController.next}" value="#{bundle.Next} #{arabaController.pagination.pageSize}" rendered="#{arabaController.pagination.hasNextPage}"/>&nbsp;


                    <p:dataTable id="araba" var="item" value="#{arabaController.mediumCarsModel}"  rowKey="#{item.idaraba}" paginator="true" rows="20"  
                                 selection="#{arabaController.selected}" selectionMode="single" >

                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{arabaController.onRowSelect}"   
                     update=":form:display :form:growl" oncomplete="carDialog.show()"  />  



                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle_idaraba}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idaraba}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle_marka}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.marka}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle_renk}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.renk}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle_yil}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.yil}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListArabaTitle_model}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.model}"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false"  
                showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  


                     <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_idaraba}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.current.idaraba}" title="#{bundle.ViewArabaTitle_idaraba}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_marka}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.current.marka}" title="#{bundle.ViewArabaTitle_marka}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_renk}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.current.renk}" title="#{bundle.ViewArabaTitle_renk}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_yil}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.current.yil}" title="#{bundle.ViewArabaTitle_yil}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_model}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{arabaController.current.model}" title="#{bundle.ViewArabaTitle_model}"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

                 </p:dialog>     


                </h:panelGroup>
                <br />
                <h:commandLink action="#{arabaController.prepareCreate}" value="#{bundle.ListArabaCreateLink}"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                <h:commandLink value="#{bundle.ListArabaIndexLink}" action="/index" immediate="true" />
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if an exception is thrown in your server log. I suspect a NullPointerException is thrown.

In the following code you refer to `bundle`, however I cannot figure out where `bundle` is pointing to.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.ViewArabaLabel_idaraba}"/>
```

If an exception is thrown in a JSF page, the rest of the page will not be rendered. This could explain why your dialog is empty.

Comment: Obviously he is referring to resources bundle (property file).

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar problem with Primefaces 3.3.1.
I had a form that included some input fields to perform a search, and then the datatable  with the search result.
What I noticed is that the AJAX requests gets a response of

```
<partial-response>
<error>
<error-name>class java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name>
<error-message>String index out of range: -1</error-message>
</error>
</partial-response>
```

I get absolutely no server-side errors.
I then re-arranged my Facelet page, I put the search input fields in their own `<h:form>` and the datatable in another `<h:form>` with different ids.
This seemed to make things a lot better.